# What opportunities do scopes offer to mobile operators?

Tags: application-development, scopes

Mobile phone operators are often concerned with providing a means to provide differentiation in the OS they ship, while not increasing the maintenance cost due to potential fragmentation.

This might be something that Ubuntu Touch can help with with the scopes technology.

What are the benefits of Scopes in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes provide the backend for all user searches in the Dash, which is the main entry point for most user journeys.

As such, scopes have a great impact on what is presented to the user in response to search queries, but also in the default view when no query is entered. Operators can implement their own scopes to add to or replace existing ones and that way influence user experience and provide differentiation to a great extent.